# Can't resolve image while using it via css background image? Not being able to use anything from assets in Ionic?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic-react, ionic6

I'm trying to load an image in one of my components and for this, I created one sample app using the following command:

```
 ionic start yp-patient-app sidemenu --type=react --capacitor
```

After completion, I moved to one of the component and tried to use a pre-existing image via:

```
.container {
    background-image: url("./assets/shapes.svg");
}
```

But it failed with an error and I'm not being able to use that file, I tried all the other combinations related to relative path like `../assets or shapes.svg, /assets/shapes`:

```
[react-scripts] Error: Can't resolve './assets/shapes.svg' in 'C:\Users\Ashish Bairwa\Desktop\temp\yp-patient-app\src\pages'
```

[image]

Here is my package.json preview:

```
{
  "name": "yp-patient-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.3.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.0",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.6",
    "@ionic/react": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^6.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.15",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "ionicons": "^5.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-streams": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!(@ionic/react|@ionic/react-router|@ionic/core|@stencil/core|ionicons)/)'",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.3.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: it should be like this: ` background-image: url("/assets/shapes.svg");`

Comment: Tried, not working @MostafaHarb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be related to a react-scripts version that comes with ionic. The latest version no longer looks into the public folder for assets. Instead, it expects you to make a folder outside the public. If you want to pick assets from the public then revert react scripts to 3.4.1